# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy error when registering with Gmail in Angular

Tags: angular, google-api, asp.net-core-webapi, google-api-key-restrictions

I have made Google Api Key adjustments (the article I am referring to: https://www.gencayyildiz.com/blog/asp-net-core-identity-angular-14-esliginde-google-login /) i wanted to print the information to the console to see if it was coming, but I got a cross-origin-opener-policy error, how can I solve it??

As I mentioned above, I get such an error on the console.

Comment: welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example]